# when "storing and printing" the variable in python ("decimal to binary" and "binary to decimal" conversion)

Tags: python, binary, numbers, decimal, data-conversion

in python while using float type

ex: >> a=0.2

```
  >> a

  >> 0.2
```

in the above example when storing "0.2" in variable "a"  it will store internally in binary format as "0.0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011"

when trying to print the variable a it will be converting binary to decimal(float) conversion as "0.199 999 999 999 818 101 059 645 414 352 416 992 187 5"

when "0.1+0.2-0.3 is not equal to 0.0" (it is not approximate) then 
how it is printing as "0.2" in the output ?

Comment: It's rounded. (Also, those are not the right values.)

Comment: when "0.1+0.2-0.3 is not equal to 0.0" (it is not approximate) then 

how it is printing as "0.2" in the output ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how your numbers should look using various python functions

```
import struct
value=0.2
data = struct.pack('d',value) 
print(data)   # -->  b'\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99\xc9?'
b'\xcd\xccL>'.hex()  # -->  '9a9999999999c93f'
 bin(0x9a9999999999c93f)      #--> '0b1001101010011001100110011001100110011001100110011100100100111111'
struct.unpack('d',data)  #--> (0.2,)
```

Comment: when "0.1+0.2-0.3 is not equal to 0.0" (it is not approximate) then 

how it is printing as "0.2" in the output ?